# INSERTING Data into table with placeholders

Tags: terms

I am trying to insert data into a table, getting errors, I have tried messaging the data, but cannot seem to get it to work, can you please help me figure out what I did wrong, please...

Here is my code I execute after validation is done:

```
                   $sql = 'INSERT INTO `tablename` (`file`,`afile`,`type`,`keyword`,`location`,`numbl`,`userul`,`uldate`) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%d) "'. $_REQUEST['filename'] . '", "' . $url . '", "' . $_REQUEST['filetype'] . '", "' . $_REQUEST['filekeyword'] . '", "' . $_REQUEST['filelocation'] . '", "' . $_REQUEST['filenumbl'] . '", "' . $user_login . '", "' . time() . '"';
                    $wpdb->query($sql);
                    $_tbInsertId = $wpdb->insert_id;
```

It is not working. I added the show errors code and it says this:

```
  WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%d) "LK-Contractor-NOGglRev-16Ld-082214.csv"' at line 1]
```

I even tried putting a comma AFTER the closing ) in values... but same error. I added "quote" marks around all of the fields, that did not fix it either.

Do you see what is causing it?
Thanks,
Richard

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, in the codex. I just used it's code and adapted it, this code:

```
  $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( 
"
    INSERT INTO $wpdb->postmeta
    ( post_id, meta_key, meta_value )
    VALUES ( %d, %s, %s )
", 
    10, 
$metakey, 
$metavalue 
) );
```

So it works now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still facing the issue try printing the query

```
echo $sql = 'INSERT INTO `tablename` (`file`,`afile`,`type`,`keyword`,`location`,`numbl`,`userul`,`uldate`) values ("'. $_REQUEST['filename'] . '", "' . $url . '", "' . $_REQUEST['filetype'] . '", "' . $_REQUEST['filekeyword'] . '", "' . $_REQUEST['filelocation'] . '", "' . $_REQUEST['filenumbl'] . '", "' . $user_login . '", "' . time() . '"';


// $wpdb->query($sql);
// $_tbInsertId = $wpdb->insert_id;
```

Now run the printed query direct in phpmyadmin to check the issue if any of value is missing

Hope it will help